# JSF (JavaServer Faces) support of html5 history.pushState() for page navigation without reloading

Tags: java, html, jsf, jsf-2

Is this possible to use html5 history.pushState() to navigate between JSF pages without full page reloading as it is done in the following sample?
https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax